# How do I replace the last period found before the first comma sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Pretty new to bash/Linux and I'm trying to do the following

I have a csv with hostnames and other information like so

```
host1.servers.com,serverA,location
host2.servers2.farm.com,serverb,location
a.servers.farm.farms.com,serverc,location
```

I need to replace the last period in the first row with (dot), but everything I've tried using sed doesn't work.  I am able to do it by cutting then performing the substitution but then I lose the remaining fields

How can I run sed and so I don't lose the other two columns like I do when I run cut -d ',' -f 1 |sed commad

So it should look like this

```
host1.servers(.)com,serverA,location
host2.servers2.farm(.)com,serverb,location
a.servers.farm.farms(.)test,serverc,location
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
$ echo a.servers.farm.farms.com,serverc,location|sed -r 's/\.([^.,]+),/(.)\1,/'
a.servers.farm.farms(.)com,serverc,location
$
```